# How can I discover a RaspberryPi Host-Address in Android

Tags: android, networking, raspberry-pi, discovery

I am working on an Android app that is able to control GPIO pins etc of a RaspberryPi. At the moment, I have to enter the IP-Address manually.

Is there some way to add a discovery-function, which finds the RaspberryPi in a network?

I want something which works out of the box when connecting the phone to wifi and connecting the RPi to the same network.

As far as I know all RaspberryPi devices start with the same MAC-Address prefix.

Comment: Set a static IP on the RaspberryPi?

Comment: you could setup a DNS. that's how names are usually resolved to ips. WINS can also work in some cases.

Comment: @MorrisonChang, I want that other users of the app can use a discovery function immediately after plugging in a RPi to a DHCP router without having to find out the IP-address (or logging in and changing it to static)

Comment: Which port do you use? Is an own server started and running automatically on your rasp?

Comment: @greenapps I'm running an own server application (in python), on port 10000 (server-socket)

Answer (score 0):

Just try to connect to several ip addresses which your raspi could have. Use port 10000. If your android device ip for instance is 192.168.1.6 then try all ip's from 192.168.1.3 to for instance 192.168.1.25. Don't try the 6. Set a socket connect time out of one second about otherwise you have to wait and wait before a connection times out.

Comment: Thank you for the tip! :) I'll try that out.